# Server Role to execute SQL Server Agent Jobs in SQL SERVER 2008

Tags: sql-server, security, sql-server-2008, ssis

The users from other departments ask me to grant them to execute Schedule Jobs / SSIS in SQL Server Agent.  At present, they cannot see SQL Server Agent tree in their ManagmentStudio.  I think, it's because they don't have the rights to execute them.

So, I would like to know which server role should I give to them.  I only want to give them minimum privileges.  When I check the existing roles in my server, I could only see the following server roles

1. bulkadmin
2. dbcreator
3. diskadmin
4. processadmin
5. public
6. securityadmin
7. serveradmin
8. setupadmin
9. sysadmin

Please advise me.

Comment: what edition of ssms they are using?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It isn't a server role.

It is one of the ["SQL Server Agent Fixed Database Roles"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188283.aspx) in msdb

See ["How to: Configure a User to Create and Manage SQL Server Agent Jobs (SQL Server Management Studio)" on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187901.aspx)