# Execute One Sql Agent Job by 2 users

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-agent-job, sql-agent

I have a scenario, where there is a dev and prod environment. All SSIS development will happen in dev SQL Server, and later it's given to a separate team to deploy in production.

So now my requirement is, as a developer of the SSIS package, I should be able to connect to the prod server through SSMS and execute the job deployed by the other team in prod. And I should not be able to see any other jobs on the server.

What is the best setup for this scenario?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Server Role to execute SQL Server Agent Jobs in SQL SERVER 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212598/server-role-to-execute-sql-server-agent-jobs-in-sql-server-2008)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SSMS UI can only do what it can do. Beyond the approach outlined by JodyT, where you'll be able to see all jobs but only executed the ones you own, you are asking for something custom, therefore you're going to need a custom solution.

In this case, I would most likely solve the problem with a stored procedure. We'll leverage the [EXECUTE AS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188354.aspx) clause to let you run the stored procedure but when it runs, the actions will be performed as the privileged user.

`msdb.dbo.sp_start_job` is the method that is called when you right click on a job and "Start Job at Step..."

Knowing that, the name of the job you want to run and the person who *can* run it is all you need to create the appropriate stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE 
    dbo.AnandPhadkeRunJob
WITH EXECUTE AS 'domain\username'
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_startjob @job_name = 'Do Something';
END
```

Here I create a stored procedure that starts the job called "Do Something" and runs it under the context of the "username" domain account. Tailor that to match your environment.

Comment: Thanks billinkc. This is really a good workaround for this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

[This page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188283(v=sql.120).aspx) describes the different database roles available for the SQL Server Agent.

If you're the owner of the job and you are member of the `SQLAgentUserRole` database role then you will be able to execute the jobs you own. You will however also be able to see other jobs but won't be able to do anything with these jobs.

Comment: Here my problem is, the jobs are deployed in production by specific team with their login to sql serever. So the jobs will be owned by them. So when I connect to the prod server using SSMS I am not able to execute them

Comment: You asked for the best setup. I gave the information that can be used to setup the jobs with the correct permissions. Now you need to work together with your production team to fix this problem. I can't do that for you.